# test coverage report for android instrumentation tests

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to generate test coverage report for android integration tests and followed blog but it didn't helped me. Basically I have jacoco.gradle file, which is

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

check.dependsOn 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.7.1.201405082137"
}

def coverageSourceDirs = [
        'src/main/java',
]

def coverageExcludedDirs = [
        '**/R*.class',
        '**/BuildConfig*.class',
        '**/*Exception.class',
        '**/*$InjectAdapter.class',
        '**/*$ModuleAdapter.class',
        '**/*$ViewInjector*.class',
        '**/sdk/*Json.class',
        '**/sdk/*Service.class',
        '**/sdk/PRNGFixes.class',
        '**/sdk/*$LinuxPRNGSecureRandom.class'
]

def coverageDir = './build/intermediates/classes/debug'

task jacoco(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "test") {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        xml.destination = "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/jacoco.xml"
        html.enabled = true
        html.destination = "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/html"
    }

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: coverageDir,
            excludes: coverageExcludedDirs
    )
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files("$buildDir/jacoco/testDebug.exec")
}
```

Then I have directory where my integration test sites.

integration_test --src/androidTest/java/com/testPackage

In build.gradle

```
apply from: '../../config/jacoco/jacoco.gradle'

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }

 sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/androidTest')
        }
    }
```

When i run gradle jacoco task it doesn't generate test coverage report in build/report folder. Can you please advise?